# Keras ImageDataGenerator unintentionally changes the color of my images when saving to directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to take an input image and save 10 augmented versions of that image using the flow method of a ImageDataGenerator object. The issue is that it's unintentionally changing the color of my image, even when I pass no arguments into the ImageDataGenerator class.

Here's my input image and code with my output image below. I'm using Tensorflow 2.2.0

[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjeAp.jpg)

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img = image.load_img(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.jpg')
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = img_array.reshape((1,) + img_array.shape)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator() #no arguments, no augmentations
save_to_dir = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop'

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(img_array, batch_size=1, save_to_dir=save_to_dir, save_format='jpg'):
    if i == 9:
        break
    i += 1
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTK4z.jpg)

The color of the image is drastically different. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the ImageDataGenerator.flow method automatically re-scales your image without being able to disable it while using the save_to_dir argument. I was able to fix this issue with the following code.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img = image.load_img(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.jpg')
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = img_array.reshape((1,) + img_array.shape)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator() #no arguments, no augmentations
save_to_dir = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop'

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(img_array, batch_size=1, save_format='jpg'):
    img_save = image.array_to_img(batch[0], scale=False) #scale=False did the trick
    img_save.save(save_to_dir + fr'\augment_{i}.jpg') #save image manually
    if i == 9:
        break
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the NumPy array that comes from datagen has dtype as float32 which is not supported dtype. Whenever the dype is **float32** it will clip the value of array before saving or displaying.
Try converting the dtype of img_array that comes from datagen to **int32** or **uint8** before saving.

Comment: Converting the dtype to int32 or uint8 right before the for loop didn't work and neither did changing it inside the for loop and saving the image manually. However in trying your suggestion I realized that the ImageDataGenerator class is automatically rescaling my RGB channels so that the min(RGB) becomes black and max(RGB) becomes white. I was able to fix this by using the array_to_image function of the Keras image module and setting scale=False. I think there should be an argument in ImageDataGenerator.flow that allows you to set scale=False without having to do it manually inside the loop.

Comment: Can you plz accept and upvote if the solution worked.

Comment: Yes! So I did upvote but since this is my first question on stackoverflow it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

And changing the dtype to int32 or uint8 didn't work in this case.